# 4 different side by side ULs - Equal li height per row

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, html-lists

I have 4 unordered lists with an identical amount of li items.
They are side by side in the display.
Is there an easy way to tell EVERY child li item (ul-one li:nth-child(1), ul-two li:nth-child(1), etc) to have the same height? The reasoning being as I fill in data, one UL gets much taller than the rest and it breaks the structure.

I can think of several ways to accomplish this:

jQuery (parent('ul') = nth-child index)

CSS w/ Classes per row

Convert to Table

None of these are ideal :-( Are there any pseudo elements in CSS to auto configure this without a specific class for all 4 list items? Let me demonstrate an example...

http://www.sinsysonline.com/repair/price.html

(Select Pick Up to view the price grid)

Here is my HTML Markup:

```
<div id="price_charts">
<div id="pri_drop-off" class="grid_12">

    <ul class="pricing_table">
        <li class="price_block">
        <a href="dropoff.html"><h2>&nbsp;</h2></a>
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure price_con">
                    <span class="price_number">&nbsp;</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="features serv">
                <li class="category"><a href="services_hwrep.html">Hardware Repair</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_netts.html">Network Troubleshooting</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_printsetup.html">Printer Setup</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_osinstall.html">Operating System Install</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_email.html">E-Mail Setup</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_compsetup.html">Computer Setup</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_swinstall.html">Software Install</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_tune.html">Computer Tune Up</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_hwup.html">Hardware Upgrade</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_backup.html">Data Backup &amp; Recovery</a></li>
                <li class="category"><a href="services_wifi.html">Wireless Troubleshooting</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="price_block">
            <a href="pickup.html"><h3>Desktop</h3></a>
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure">
                    <span class="price_number">$30</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">per hour</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="features">
                <li><a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_netts.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_printsetup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_osinstall.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_email.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_compsetup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_swinstall.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_tune.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_hwup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_backup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_wifi.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="contact.html" class="action_button">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="price_block">
            <a href="onsite.html"><h3>Laptop</h3></a>
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure">
                    <span class="price_number">$50</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">per hour</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="features">
                <li><a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_netts.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_printsetup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_osinstall.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_email.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_compsetup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_swinstall.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_tune.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_hwup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_backup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_wifi.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="contact.html" class="action_button">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="price_block">
            <a href="remote.html"><h3>Server</h3></a>
            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure">
                    <span class="price_number">$30</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">per hour</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="features">
                <li><a href="services_hwrep.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_netts.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_printsetup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_osinstall.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_email.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_compsetup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_swinstall.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_tune.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_hwup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_backup.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="services_wifi.html"><img src="../css/images/check.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="contact.html" class="action_button">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And current JS for hover effects:

```
$('ul.features li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {

    $('ul.features > li:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').toggleClass('pri_active');
    $('ul.features > li.category:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ' )').toggleClass('pri_cat');
});
```

And a whole lot of CSS I'll save you the time to decipher.

So, basic question:

Is there a CSS way to tell EVERY equivalent child element to auto resize to largest child among the 4? (without saying (:first-child, :nth-child(2), etc)

Comment: Never had a post be voted down before a response came hah

Comment: That's tabular data you're shoving into lists.

Comment: I'm assuming that the solution should be to ditch the divs and create a table, hmmm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small jquery scripts will do..

See DEMO on jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/VcEPT/

## CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    font-size:11px;
}
ul{
    float:left;
    width:95%;
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin:1%;
    background:#dfdfdf; 
}
```

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="price_block">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    </li>
    <li class="price_block">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    </li>
    <li class="price_block">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </li>
    <li class="price_block">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </li>
</ul>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_height = 0;
    $('li.price_block:lt(4)').each(function() {
        if( $(this).height() > max_height )
        max_height = $(this).height();                  
    }); 
    // try to comment On and Off this line
    $('li.price_block').css( "height", max_height+'px' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's tabular data, use a table - the example you mentioned gets away with using lists because the rows are the same height.

If you want the pop up effect, place divs within each cell, apply classes to these divs according to column, then onmouseover, set a negative top to all divs with the same class.

A simple example (not very efficient, I know, feel free to improve) + [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjdxk/2/):

HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='column first'></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='column second'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='column first'></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='column second'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.column{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;   
}
.column.first{
    background:red;
}
.column.second{
    background:blue;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.column.first').mouseover(function(){$('.column.first').each(function(){$(this).css('top', -10);});});
$('.column.first').mouseout(function(){$('.column.first').each(function(){$(this).css('top', 0);});});
$('.column.second').mouseover(function(){$('.column.second').each(function(){$(this).css('top', -10);});});
$('.column.second').mouseout(function(){$('.column.second').each(function(){$(this).css('top', 0);});});
```